# PayPal Recurring Payments & Fixed Membership Type

Tags: paypal, recurring-contributions, ipn, auto-renew, renewals

I am new to CiviCRM, and still feeling my way around. This issue starts with some IPN failure notifications we're getting from PayPal. Researching these, I found they are only occurring on recurring payments.

These are going through, which led me to see how these recurring payments are being set up. We have a FIXED 1 year membership. The PayPay recurring payments, however, are being set for 1 year from the initial subscription, or the ROLLING type.

Setting the IPN error aside for the moment, I am unclear on how FIXED memberships should be working with PayPal. They are being set as ROLLING. Is there a way to uncouple CiviCRM Auto-Renew from PayPal and manage it manually? Or is there something I am missing to have PayPal manage FIXED correctly?

This is CiviCRM 5.21.0, payment processor PayPal - Website Payments Standard

Comment: Hi Mark and welcome. I think you are right in that when the instructions get sent to the payment processor, they get sent as 'take this money now and take it again in 12 months" so despite having used Civi for 13 years perhaps we have been lucky that the only clients who wanted to offer recurring Memberships were not using Fixed period. Sorry I can't be of more help